# How do I correctly deal with non-breaking spaces using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse an HTML page, but I am having odd problems with non-breaking spaces. I tried different encodings, replacing the whitespace, and a few other headache inducing attempts.

Here is the HTML snippet in question:

```
<td>Amount 15,300&nbsp;at&nbsp;dollars</td>
```

Note the change for the `&nbsp;` representation after I use Nokogiri:

```
<td>Amount 15,300&#xa0;at&#xa0;dollars</td>
```

And outputting the `inner_text`:

```
Amount 15,300Â atÂ dollars
```

This is my base Nokogiri grab, I did try a few alternatives to solve but failed miserably:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

And then I do a `doc.search` for the item in question.

Note that if I look at the doc, the line shows up with the `&#xa0;` on that line.

Clarification: I do not think I clearly stated the difficulty I am having. I can't get the `inner_text` to show up without the strange `Â` symbol.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is equivalent to `&#xa0;` or `&#160;`. The problem is not with nokogiri. In fact, it is doing a great job of normalizing it. Something is wrong with displaying it. What browser are you seeing it on?

Comment: I recognize that Nokogiri is doing what it is supposed to be doing; my problem is that I am trying to get rid of them, but all my attempts at replacing the text have failed. It could just be me trying to use it incorrectly. I use the inner_text and then just output to view, no browser.

Comment: But aren't you using a browser to see the (rendered result of) view? How else can you see it?

Comment: I am just outputting the inner_text right to the console, via the "puts" method; I am trying to grab the data within the tags. It's the Â that is driving me crazy.

Comment: If your output is to the console, you should have clearly stated so in the question. That is the most crucial part. The question is not about nokogiri, but is how to output certain characters to the console.

Comment: I realized that after reading some of the answers, and added the clarification at the end of the description; unfortunately I cannot change the actual question. I also originally thought it was Nokogiri related because the behavior did not happen when I used Hpricot. Turns out Nokogiri does cause the odd behavior, but you are right that it is about output.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really, really want to keep the `&nbsp;` notation, there shouldn't be a problem here.

`A0` is the hex character code for a non-breaking space. As such, `&#xa0;` prints a non-breaking space, and is exactly equivalent to `&nbsp;`. `&#160;` does the same thing, too.

What Nokogiri is doing here is reading the text node, recognizing the entities, and converting them to their actual string representation internally. Then, when converting it back to an HTML-friendly version of the text node, it represents the non-breaking space by its hex code, rather than taking the performance overhead of looking it up in an entity table, since it's equivalent, anyway.

Assuming that `Â` was what you were seeing and wasn't just an issue pasting into StackOverflow, this is a text encoding issue: the output software (browser?) isn't in UTF-8 mode, so doesn't know how to handle character code `A0`, so does the best it can. If this is a browser, adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the head will solve this issue, and will make the rest of the output more Unicode-friendly.

If you really, really want `&nbsp;`, use `gsub` to replace them in your final output. Otherwise, don't worry about it.

Comment: The issue is the Â on a simple inner_text output, where I am trying to parse the data to put into a database. I tried setting the doc.encoding to utf-8 (strangely, I don't think I tried that encoding until I read your reply), but that did not fix it either. I think the problem is that I am not trying to search for the right character to eliminate.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but it took me an hour to find out how to solve this problem, and it is really easy once you know. Just pass your string to this function and it will be "de-nbsp-fied".

```
def strip_html(str)
  nbsp = Nokogiri::HTML("&nbsp;").text
  str.gsub(nbsp,'')
end
```

You could also replace it whith a space if you wished. May many of you find this answer!

Answer (score 0):

As @sawa says, the main problem is what you see when writing to the console. It's not correctly displaying the non-breaking space after Nokogiri converts it to the appropriate binary value.

The usual way to fix the problem is to preprocess the content:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<td>Amount 15,300&nbsp;at&nbsp;dollars</td>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html.gsub(/&(?:#xa0|#160|nbsp);/i, ' '))
puts doc.to_html
```

Which outputs:

```
<td>Amount 15,300 at dollars</td>
```